# How can I compare version numbers in SQLAlchemy? (Given a function to do so)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, comparator

I have this function for comparing version numbers:

```
def version_gt(left, right):
    """
    Compare two version numbers telling which is greater    

    Returns True if left is greater, False if right is greater.
    """
    left = map(int, filter(None, str(left).split('.')))
    right = map(int, filter(None, str(right).split('.')))
    for i in range(max([len(left), len(right)])):
        if i > len(left)-1:
            # left ran out of version numbers, therefore right is greater
            return False
        elif i > len(right)-1:
            # right ran out of version numbers therefore left is greater
            return True
        else:
            # compare versions only if the version number is different
            if left[i] != right[i]:
                return left[i] > right[i]
    return False # if all is equal, return False since left is not greater
```

How can I use this in SQLAlchemy to compare version numbers in a select statement?

I couldn't figure out the online documentation. Thanks for your help.
-Sunjay03

[EDIT] Here is how I have defined the columns:

```
Table("updates", metadata,
    Column("u_id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("appname", String, nullable=False),
    Column("version", String, nullable=False),
    Column("uploaded", DateTime, default=func.now()),
)
```

The answer has something to do with this:
http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/mapper_config.html#custom-comparators

I couldn't understand it very well, maybe you can.

Comment: can you show us the `Column` definition of the data element you'd like to compare?  This will also likely depend on the database you intend to use.

Comment: I am using SQLite for my database. I'll add the column definition in just a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sqlite database engine is not quite expressive enough to do that kind of comparison on a single column, even in raw SQL.  The best option will be to split out the `version` column into several, or to simply accept a simple string comparison (something to the effect of `updates1.version > updates2.version`.  If none of those are an option, you will need to extend the sqlite engine (via [`sqlite_create_function()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html)) with the function you need.

Comment: Thanks! I just changed it to compare them directly using a greater than operator instead of my function. I didn't know that would work, thanks!